# npm verb stack Error: 404 Not Found: error-inject@^1.0.0

Tags: npm, koa

Try to make `npm install` with :

```
 $ node -v
 v11.7.0
 $ npm -v
 6.5.0
```

But get an error after `npm debug`:

> npm verb stack Error: 404 Not Found: error-inject@^1.0.0

This is a dependency of `koa`. What can be the issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

https://status.npmjs.org/  - the problem is with npm, they try to fix it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your .npmrc file were some settings are missing or wrong and also check the
https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/459, here they resolve the issue as he said I quoted  "It's working now, I had my enterprise creds in global .npmrc file. "

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be in comments